# Crushed light bulb killed a circuit but none of the breakers tripped

Tags: electrical, wiring

My wife was putting Christmas decorations back in storage and broke the the light bulb. She said she saw sparks. An adjacent closet light which is switched no longer worked. I checked the breaker box and none of the breaker switches were tripped. I turned off all the power and removed and replaced the broken bulb. After turning on the power, the replacement bulb does not work nor the closet light either. I replaced the closet bulb and storage light fixture and nothing works. What’s next?

Comment: Some circuit breakers trip and their handle movement is so slight it's difficult to see. Have you tried flipping the applicable breaker off and then on again?

Comment: If it isn’t a gfci, next possibility is the switch. Turn off power, take the switch apart, take lots of good pictures. Bonus points if you can test continuity in the switch with a multimeter.

Answer (score 3):

You most likely have a GFCI that has opened the circuit.

Check around the house for a GFCI outlet and reset it.

They look like this [GFCI](https://www.harborfreight.com/15-amp-125v-self-test-gfci-duplex-outlet-57958.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=12169054043&campaignid=12169054043&utm_content=132335101603&adsetid=132335101603&product=57958&store=144&gclid=CjwKCAjw_MqgBhAGEiwAnYOAesxxc4IVKRy6Vdx2iexPzftCs1-V3qdJR1q9plRXzJb7Obt4QauWLxoC-G4QAvD_BwE)